# Не могу подключить google api

Tags: php, google-api

Я закинул папку с либой в `public_html` и прописал в своем файле код:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . __DIR__ . '/google-api-php-client-master/src');
```

Но классы с гугл апи не открываются, скрипт ничего не импортировал. Что я сделал не так?

Comment: @russer, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

> Выражение include включает и выполняет указанный файл. Документация ниже также относится к выражению require. Файлы включаются исходя из пути указанного файла, или, если путь не указан, используется путь, указанный в директиве include_path.
>
> http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

Написал подробную инструкцию подключение здесь:
http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/94089/

Такой подход должен сработать:

```
set_include_path ( get_include_path () . PATH_SEPARATOR . APPPATH .'application/libraries/google-api-php-client/src/Google' );         
require_once APPPATH . "libraries/google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php";         
require APPPATH . "libraries/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php";         
require APPPATH . "libraries/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Oauth2.php";
```